# How could I add Eventlisteners for each div so it's not undefined? (javascript, more below)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, project

I don't understand why it says it's `undefined`.

error message:

> dom.js:51 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backGroundcolor' of undefined
> at HTMLDivElement. (dom.js:51)

The problematic line: **`pixels.style.backGroundcolor = 'black';`**

```js
let drawBtn = document.querySelector('#letsDraw')
drawBtn.onclick = clearAndDraw

function clearAndDraw() {
  clear()
  draw()
}

function draw() {
  screenSize = textbox.value
  for (i = 0; i < screenSize ** 2; i++) {
    pixel = document.createElement('div');
    pixel.classList.add('pixel');
    pixel.style.border = '1px solid black';
    pixel.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    screen.appendChild(pixel);
  }
  screen.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${screenSize}, auto) `;
  screen.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${screenSize}, auto) `;

  const pixels = document.querySelectorAll('.pixel')
  pixels.forEach(pxl => {
    pxl.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
      pixels.style.backGroundcolor = 'black';
    })
  })
}
```

```html
<div class=screen>
</div>
```

Comment: `pxl.style.backgroundColor` instead of `pixels.style.backGroundcolor` in the second loop

Comment: side bit: do you need to quote your class name in the HTML?

Comment: Also `backGroundcolor` -> `backgroundColor`

Comment: @silversunhunter not in HTML5 if you use only *one* className. Only if you're going to add two: `class="screen foo"` - otherwise `class=screen` is **absolutely valid**

Comment: Why are you not adding the event handler when you create the div? Seems weird you create all the divs and look them all back up to add an vent handler.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan oh wow.. Learned something new!

Answer (score 1):

You are targeting pixels list and not the element itself. So if your forEach is using 'pxl' as a variable for each element, you must change this line.

**Edit:** *Another thing is a typo on your style attribute. Change 'backGroundcolor' to 'backgroundColor'*

```
pixels.style.backGroundcolor = 'black';
```

To this

```
pxl.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I already tried this before but maybe for some other reason it didn't worked, now it's good to go

Comment: Yeh @RokoC.Buljan. Totally agree. I mistyped during my edition. Now it's correct.